# Tzitzis when reciting Shema?

Tags: tzitzis, shema

Are there halachic sources stating one must wear tzitzis when reciting the Shema or is this minhag?

Comment: I'm not sure how much more clear the question can be. Is it halacha or minhag?

Comment: then how come you had to ask a follow up below?

Comment: What if a Halakhic source says it's a Minhag? Does that qualify?

Comment: What do you mean by "must"? Mitzva? Chovah? That Shema doesn't count without it? That unlike the rest of the time a four cornered garment is obligatory to be worn? (Yehareig veAl Yaavor?)

Comment: Are you asking just about the morning Shema when there is a Mitzva of Tzitzit in general?

Comment: Shmuel's answer didn't address the question of it being halacha or minhag, only what one does with tzitzit during the recitation. That's the reason for the follow up. It did not occur to me that it could be both halacha and minhag. I presumed it would be either/or, but thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: "or is this Minhag"... Is it what? Please edit to finish your sentence

Comment: You have plenty of room to write your question clearly. Please use it in the future. Don't feel constrained to fit everything in one sentence, but rather provide motivation and background to your post, define your terms and question clearly, avoid jargon, use proper grammar, etc. For now I've put the question on hold to prevent any misunderstandings by potential volunteer expert helpers (aka answerers) while you improve it.

Comment: shmuels answer brought "halachic sources stating one must wear tzitzis when reciting the Shema" (well they say to hold it not wear it; I don't know if that qualifies since I don't know why you are asking). It totally answers [a plausible construal of] your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 17:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.17.7?set-language-cookie)

> קוֹדֵם קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע כְּשֶׁאוֹמֵר וַהֲבִיאֵנוּ וְכוּ' נוֹטֵל אֵת הַצִּיצִית בְּיָדוֹ, וְאוֹחֲזָן בִּשְׁעַת קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע בְּיַד שְׂמֹאל בֵּין קְמִיצָה לְזֶרֶת כְּנֶגֶד לִבּוֹ, וּכְשֶׁמַּגִּיעַ לְוַיֹּאמֶר שֶׁהִיא פָּרָשַׁת צִיצִית, אוֹחֲזָן גַּם בִּימִינוֹ, וּכְשֶׁאוֹמֵר וּרְאִיתֶם אוֹתוֹ, נוֹתְנָם עַל הָעֵינַיִם, וּמִסְתַּכֵּל בָּהֶם וְנוֹשְׁקָן. וְנוֹהֲגִין שֶׁבְּכָל פַּעַם שֶׁאוֹמֵר תֵּבַת צִיצִית, נוֹשְׁקָן, וְאוֹחֲזָן עַד וְנֶחְמָדִים לָעַד, שֶׁאָז נוֹשְׁקָן וּמַנִּיחָן מִיָּדָיו. (ס"ד).
>
> Before reading the Shema, when saying; Vahavi'enu, (and bring us) etc. take the tzitzis of the tallis in your hand and hold them while reading the Shema. They should be held with the left hand, grasped between the ring finger and little finger and held near the heart. When Vayomer, the section concerning tzitzis is read, the tzitzis should also be held in the right hand. When saying Ure'isem oso, (and you will look upon it) touch them to your eyes, look upon them and kiss them. It is customary to kiss them each time the word tzitzis is said. They should be held until the words, Venechemadim la'ad are said; after which they should be kissed and released.

[Shulchan Aruch Orach C. 24:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.24.2?set-language-cookie)

> מצוה לאחוז הציצית ביד שמאלית כנגד לבו בשעת קריאת שמע רמז לדבר והיו הדברים האלה וגו' על לבבך:
>
> It is a Mitzvah to grasp the Tzitzit with your left hand near your heart while reciting Kriat Shema. This is alluded to [in the verse] "And these words shall be...on your heart".

Comment: thank you for your answer. Would it not be a mitzvah to recite the Shema even if tzitzit were not available for some reason?

Comment: I think the Mitzvah of reciting the Shema and having the tzititz handy are completely separate, and also on different planes.

Comment: @Ephraim77 Welcome to MY. Just FYI it is good practice to upvote an answer if you found it helpful (which I assume it is since you start with thank you). I hope you take this in a positive way since I see you are still an early user of this site.

Comment: @mbloch Thank you for pointing that out. I was not aware as I am new to this site.